# AngularJS form control directive with isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive to render a select element with some specific values. Here is the code:

The template of the directive:

```
<select id="{{name}}"
  class="form-control"
  ng-model="selectedOption"
  ui-jq="selectpicker"
  ui-options='{ iconBase: "famfamfam-flag", tickIcon: "fa fa-check" }'>
<option ng-repeat="o in data" value="{{o.id}}">{{o.label}}</option>
```

Directive code:

```
(function () {
appModule.directive('yesNoDeclineCombo', ['$timeout', 
function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/yesNoDeclineCombo.cshtml',
        scope: {
            selectedOption: '=?',
            name: '@'
        },
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            $scope.data = app.consts.yesNoDeclineData;
            $scope.data.unshift({ id: null, label: 'Not Assigned' });

            //refresh combo
            $timeout(function () {
                $(element).selectpicker('refresh');
            });

            $scope.$watch('selectedOption', function (newValue) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $(element).selectpicker('refresh');
                }, 0);
            });
        }
    };
}
]);
})();
```

Markup use:

```
<yes-no-decline-combo selected-option="vm.specialDietId"
     ng-required="vm.isFieldRequired('SpecialDiet')" name="SpecialDiet">
</yes-no-decline-combo>
```

Markup rendering:

```
<select id="SpecialDiet" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-isolate-scope ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" ng-model="selectedOption" ui-jq="selectpicker" ui-options="{ iconBase: &quot;famfamfam-flag&quot;, tickIcon: &quot;fa fa-check&quot; }" selected-option="vm.specialDietId" ng-required="vm.isFieldRequired('SpecialDiet')" name="SpecialDiet" required="required" tabindex="-98">
<!-- ngRepeat: o in data --><option ng-repeat="o in data" value="" class="ng-binding ng-scope" selected="selected">Not assigned</option><!-- end ngRepeat: o in data --><option ng-repeat="o in data" value="1" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Yes</option><!-- end ngRepeat: o in data --><option ng-repeat="o in data" value="2" class="ng-binding ng-scope">No</option><!-- end ngRepeat: o in data --><option ng-repeat="o in data" value="3" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Decline To Answer</option><!-- end ngRepeat: o in data -->
```

How would I be able to make the directive render the ng-model as:

```
ng-model="vm.specialDietId"
```

instead of

```
ng-model="selectedOption"
```

The reason I need this behavior is because of another attribute directive that reads the model property the ngModel is bound to and do some other functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try to replace `scope: {...` with `scope: true` to share values from outer scope. Today this is recognized as bad habit, but if you have to, it should work. Of course, you have to also change `{{name}}` binding.

Comment: What changes when I use scope:true? Thanks

Comment: @Bill Your `$scope` won't be isolated: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28867992/3368498